# Multiple K8s Issues relating to Webhooks, Logs & I/O Timeouts

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-ingress, metrics

I have a really weird issue with one of my Linode K8s clusters running 1.23, there are multiple issues occuring and I can't quite pinpoint the root cause.

Linode have let me know it is not a issue with the master and nothing on there end, let me highlight all the identified problems to start.

**Logs not Working**

When trying to pull logs from any pods I get this error (which makes it very hard to troubleshoot)

```
root@aidan:~# kubectl logs <pod-name> -n revwhois-subdomain-enum
Error from server: Get "https://192.168.150.102:10250/containerLogs/revwhois-subdomain-enum/tldbrr-revwhois-worker12-twppv/tldbrr-revwhois-worker12": dial tcp 192.168.150.102:10250: i/o timeout
```

**Metrics not Working**

```
root@m0chan:~# kubectl top nodes
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

**Pod Deletion not Working**

When deleting a pod with `kubectl delete pod <pod-name> - <namespace>` - it will *delete* the pod however it is stuck in a terminating state, the old pod is not deleted and anew pod is not launched.

**Errors Editing Ingress**

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "yaml/xxx/xxx-ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=30s: Temporary Redirect
```

I also have errors on Metrics logs and Cert-Manager logs relating to `failed calling webhook`

This is all for now and I would really appreciate some help resolving this.

Aidan

Comment: One thing I would add, is I believe Linode force updated my cluster from 1.21 to 1.23 recently so not sure if this is related

Comment: Your 1st issue seems to be related with kubelet not working which runs on port 10250 by default. Can you check whether kubelet is running in the worker node?

Comment: is there a specific way to do this? The nodes are all showing as "Ready" which would indicate that kubelet is running right? - also noticied when I access Kubernetes Dashboard GUI and select "Nodes" I get the following error. `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure`

Comment: You will need to SSH into the worker node where the specific pod was running and run `systemctl status kubelet`.

Comment: Kubelet appears to be up :)

Comment: Please share the get the logs of kubelet using `journalctl -u kubelet` and share them here.

Comment: Correction, kubelet is infact not working on this node or the others

```
Aug 26 11:48:00 lke44160-108504-6308b294798e systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 26 11:48:00 lke44160-108504-6308b294798e systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 26 11:48:10 lke44160-108504-6308b294798e systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 26 11:48:10 lke44160-108504-6308b294798e systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Aug 26 11:48:10 lke44160-108504-6308b294798e systemd[1]: Sta
```

Comment: Also have the below error

Aug 26 13:17:09 lke44160-108504-6308b294798e kubelet[930]: E0826 13:17:09.513112     930 server.go:205] "Failed to load kubelet config file" err="failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file \"/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml\", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory" path="/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"

Comment: Check if `var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` is present in the worker node or not.